# XLOOKUP result for blank values is 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

In `XLOOKUP`, the ability to use `if_not_found` is great, however, what might I do if the value is found, but the result is blank? For example:

```
A:Subnet     B:Description
10.0.1.0/24  Basement
10.0.2.0/24
10.0.3.0/24  Upstairs
```

I want `XLOOKUP("10.0.2.0/24",$A:$A,$B:$B,"",0)` to return a blank, but since the *search* text is found (but there's nothing in the result), the result displays a `0`. I want it to be blank if either the **search text is not found** or **if the resultant set is empty**. Neither my tinkering nor my Googling has not borne fruit... thoughts?

Comment: add `&""` to the end.

Comment: or a space in the empty cell...

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott... that's the answer!

Comment: There is a [lengthy discussion here](https://www.exceldemy.com/xlookup-return-blank-instead-of-0/) with same subject

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `&""` after the formula. For example:

```
XLOOKUP(C3,B6:B10,E6:E10)&""
```

(@Scott Craner's helpful comment formatted as an answer)

Comment: So simple! Never thought of doing this before - thank you (Scott too :)

Comment: But this change result type to string and can not be used for numerical functions such as  `AVERAGE`.